# Erro ao executar setup.py em Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Olá,
toda vez que tento executar um arquivo `setup.py` encontro o seguinte erro:

```
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Já tentei instalar

```
   python setup.py install
```

e

```
python setup.py build
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Esse retorno dá mesmo quando você define o "install" ou "build"?

Comment: Sim, defino e me retorna a mensagem. Conferi as versões do Python e os arquivos e estão todas corretos também

Comment: É algum módulo em específico que está tentando instalar?

Comment: São vários, o ultimo utilizado foi um 

`try:
    from setuptools import setup
    extra = dict(test_suite="tests.test.suite", include_package_data=True)
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    extra = {}

import sys`

Comment: Ja tentei importar um da Bovespa também

Comment: Estranho. Tem como linkar um exemplo do módulo que tentou instalar e descrever todos os passos? Se for possível prints ou gif da tela até ficaria legal.